# get a value form json data in react.js

Tags: javascript, json

how can i access the (downlod_link) from this json file?
i using this way? but it is not work

```
<NavLink href={"http://localhost:8000/storage/"+files['data']['resume'].download_link}>Resume</NavLink>
```

this is my code:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/file"+path)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    files: json,
})
})
}


  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
      let {files} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="dark" dark expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">OSAMA Portfolio</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href={"http://localhost:8000/storage/"+files['data']['resume'].download_link}>Resume</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a download link in any of the JSON you're showing, so it feels like you've not properly explained what you need to do. (On the React side, you obviously already have access to all the information, so that's probably not your question)

Comment: just review the image attached, it is for json data

Comment: That's not a just - there is nothing in your post that explains where that JSON is even supposed to come from. On the React side, you _already have access_ to the download link, because you had to _build_ it for the NavLink to even have an `href`, so why would you need it in some JSON response?

Comment: no bro, i don't access (download_link) in my code, i just try to access it, but what i does in my code not worked, my question is about how can i access (download_link) in the (href) in NavBar>>> i hope now it become more clear, thank you

Comment: I still don't understand: your code _literally shows you building that download link_ right there in your component, where _your code_ builds `<NavLink href={"http://localhost:8000/storage/"+files['data']['resume'].download_link}`. If you can build that link in `render()`, you can determine that link anywhere else in your component? And if that isn't the download link you mean, please [update your post to only include information relevant to the question](/help/how-to-ask). Ideally, show a full [mcve] so people can understand the true code flow.

Comment: yes yes, my problem in this line exactly 
{"http://localhost:8000/storage/"+files['data']['resume'].download_link},
 because this is not work, i think i use the wrong method to access (download_link), sorry because my question may be not obvious

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you to just fetch resume/letter then split/cut the string to get the download link

for example :

```
var resumeString = jsonObject.data.resume;
var downloadLink = resumeString.split(",")[0].substr(21,resumeString.length-1);
```

here you split the string to get the download link , but you still have to work in cutting some characters , .substr(21,resumeString.length-1) will cut the string from character in index 21 to the end

hope this works for you

Comment: but i thing there is a better ways to do that, because the (resume) is also array, and has one object, and (download_link) is a key in this object

Comment: @OsamaMohammed , I see the download_link prop is a non-direct string

Comment: you just have to make some processes on the string

Comment: not problem, just i want to know the method to access it